# Flutter GetX - How to manage controller deletion?

Tags: flutter, dart, controller, flutter-getx

I have a Flutter app with `GetX` Controllers. The app has 6 screens and every screen has its `GetxController`.

Screens 1 and 2 are for the login system, while screens 3 to 6 are for the app content.

After logging in the user can go forward and back between screens 3-4-5, but when he reaches screen 6 he can only go to Screen 3 and all the previous stacks must be deleted (so he cannot go back).

`1st problem`: if I do a `Get.offAll(() => const Screen3())` from the Screen 6, the Controller for Screen3 gets deleted and nothing works anymore. I workaround (don't know if that word exists! :D) by marking `Controller3` as permanent via

`Get.put(Controller3(), permanent: true)`

But here comes the

`2nd problem`: if the user presses the `logout` button (that is present only in Screen 3), this time I need the `Controller3` to be deleted. This time, calling `Get.offAll` doesn't delete the controller, nor calling `Get.delete<Controller3>()`, since it says

> "Controller3" has been marked as permanent, SmartManagement is not authorized to delete it.

I'm stuck in this situation and I really don't know what to do

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So `Getx` as you said let us make a `GetxController` permanent like this:

```
Get.put<Controller3>.put(Controller3(), permanent: true);.
```

you can't delete it normally with:

```
Get.delete<Controller3>();
```

But you have the option to delete a controller that is marked with `permanent`, by forcing its deletion with the `force` property like this:

```
Get.delete<Controller3>(force: true);
```

`force` Will delete an Instance even if marked as permanent.

Comment: I ended up doing this way...though I don't really know why bindings are not working...

Comment: perfect solution, i was thinking it is a mistake of the GET package as I am not deleting it manually still it gets deleted, but by doing this i got the answer as well as solutions, thanks

Answer (score 2):

> 1st problem: if I do a Get.offAll(() => const Screen3()) from the Screen 6, the Controller for the Screen3 gets deleted and nothing works anymore.

I didn't get the quoted part. When you route from 6 --> 3, the binding mechanism should generate the controller of screen 3 again.

By the way you can make it manually from anywhere using with

```
 var controller = Get.put(SomeController());
 controller.dispose();
```

Comment: It's exactly what I thought but for some reason it's not working. I'm gonna do a deep dive!

Comment: If U want to re initialize the sepcific contorller that already used before,  you may use “get.create”.